# Is it possible to call a dictionary value if the key is within the set key? (the dictionary keys are sets)

Tags: python

Let's say "foo" and "bar" are equal to 1.

`my_dict = { ("foo", "bar") : 1 }`

Is there a way to call `my_dict["foo"]` and get the value of `1` or is my only option to remake my input variable into the full set?

I couldn't figure out a way to just call the dictionary straight up, without first transforming the key into the set, and then I could call the dictionary.

Comment: `("foo", "bar")` is not a set but a tuple.

Comment: `my_dict = {"foo" : 1, "bar": 1 }` and `my_dict = { ("foo", "bar") : 1 }` are entirely different. You'll need the tuple object to access the value from the dictionary

Comment: You probably should have built your dict differently in the first place.

Comment: It's possible to make it so that setting the `('foo', 'bar')` key actually sets the `'foo'` and `'bar'` keys, but you'd have to make your own subclass of `dict` to do so. Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can look through the keys one by one

```
my_dict = { ("foo", "bar") : 1 }

def find_subkey(subkey):
    for key in my_dict:
        if subkey in key:
            return my_dict[key]
    raise ValueError("foo not found")
```

If you do this often, you can index the dictionary once and, assuming it doesn't change, use the index instead.

```
my_dict_index = {}
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    for sk in k:
        my_dict_index[sk] = v

print(my_dict_index["foo"])
```

If you have duplicate subkeys, this will only return one of them.